# Jquery ajax call not made

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem with jquery that the ajax call is not made.
Also the click should not get at the top of dom to trigger the hide af the .warning div.

I can see with firebug that the POST request is not made.

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if($('.warning').hasClass("active"))
        $('.warning').hide();
});

$('.ero').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/stem_op/3',
        data: {id: idv},
        success:function(msg){
        $('.warning').fadeIn(500).css({
        display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: position.left + 50,
        top: position.top - 25
    }).append(msg).addClass("active")}
        });      
});
```

Comment: is the click event being called? Is the event handler being added before the elements are ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, based on your code if it's included in the head the ero classed element doesn't exist yet. Without the .ready() your code is executing immediately.  Since you're using .click() as opposed to a delegate, there's nothing to bind to when it's executed.

Like Dyer above says, wrap it in a ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //code goes here
});
```

If you are possibly going to have an .ero element added dynamically with JS based on user interaction, you'll want to make use of [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Also, .click() is essentially a shortcut to [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) so try and start using that at least so you can namespace your events as well.  That makes binding, unbinding, and rebinding event handlers extremely easy without impacting other code that may be using the same events on that element.

```
//instead of
$(".ero").click(function(e) { });

//something like this
$(".ero").bind("click.mynamespace", function(e) {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: I have a link with the class ero

Comment: So your .click is wrapped in a document.ready()?  If so, try adding the complete method to your Ajax call. It gets two arguments, data and status. Do a console.log on the status to be sure a request is even being made.  Another option is to throw a console.log right at the beginning of the function inside of your click handler so that you can see if the event is even being captured.

Comment: It was the data, that I had forgot to remove. Now the ajax call is made.

Comment: delegate is now superceded by .on() per this documentation: [http://api.jquery.com/delegate/]http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

$('.ero') probably didn't exist yet. Try wrapping in [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), or using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$('.ero').live('click', function() { ... }
```

Comment: I have a link with the class ero